# How i can simulate a double mouse click on window ( i khow handle) on x, y coordinate, using SendInput?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse, mouseevent

How i can simulate a double mouse click on window ( i know handle of this window) on x, y coordinate, using SendInput?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
void DoubleClick(int x, int y)
{
    const double XSCALEFACTOR = 65535 / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1);
    const double YSCALEFACTOR = 65535 / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1);

    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

    double cx = cursorPos.x * XSCALEFACTOR;
    double cy = cursorPos.y * YSCALEFACTOR;

    double nx = x * XSCALEFACTOR;
    double ny = y * YSCALEFACTOR;

    INPUT Input={0};
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    Input.mi.dx = (LONG)nx;
    Input.mi.dy = (LONG)ny;

    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

    SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
    SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

    Input.mi.dx = (LONG)cx;
    Input.mi.dy = (LONG)cy;

    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;

    SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

You can use GetWindowRect() to get the window position from its handle and pass relative `x` and `y` to DoubleClick function:

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

HWND phwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

DoubleClick(rect.left + x, rect.top + y);

SetForegroundWindow(phwnd); // To activate previous window
```

Answer (score 4):

This will simulate a double click at certain coordinates

```
  SetCursorPos(X,Y);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your goal (best) or the method, but if you try to specify both, more often than not the answer is going to be "that doesn't work like that".

`SendInput` doesn't work like that, it simulates mouse activity on the screen, which will be delivered to whatever window is visible at that location (or has mouse capture), not the window of your choice.

To deliver a double-click to a specific window, try [`PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's a piece of code in [this website](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=377394). Try using the function `LeftClick()` twice in succession. That does the trick according to [this guy](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=326366).

Answer (score 0):

Since my 'reputation' is not high enough (yet), I'd like to comment on #fardjad's solution: it works great, but one might add following to the "main" routine:

```
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
SetCursorPos(rect.left + x, rect.top + y);
// which shows your current mouseposition...
// during my testing, I used a _getch() so that I actually could verify it
Sleep(nWinSleep);
// delay the mouseclick, as window might not get to foreground quick enough;
   took me awhile to figure this one out...
DoubleClick(rect.left + x, rect.top + y);
```