# C++ mouse click on certain spot in window

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have my function here working, but I am certainly going about it the wrong way.

My program uses FindWindow to find the correct window. I need to double click on a specific location on this window.

I made it work by always putting the window in the same location on the screen, but if I moved the window the program would try click on the hard-coded location I have provided and it would not work.

Here is the function:

```
void lobbyWindow(HWND main_client)
{
  //RECT arect;

   // GetWindowRect(main_client, &arect); 

    SetCursorPos(748,294);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

As you can see I just move the mouse to 748,294 and double click. What I want to do is set the mouse to 100,100 in the main_client window, so if I move the main_client window the mouse still clicks on the correct spot.

Comment: You're probably looking for [Microsoft Active Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270.aspx) instead, then you can use flags to move the cursor relative to the window -

`Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;`

1. [How i can simulate a double mouse click on window ( i khow handle) on x, y coordinate, using SendInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789843/how-i-can-simulate-a-double-mouse-click-on-window-i-khow-handle-on-x-y-coord)
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/97017/

Answer (score 3):

If the window you're clicking in is in another thread/process this approach is fundamentally flawed, because the window can move while you're sending the clicks - meaning even if you have the right position to start with there's no guarantee all the clicks will end up in the same place.

Having said that, you can convert a client-relative coordinate to screen-coordinates using the `ClientToScreen` API function:

```
POINT pt = { 100, 100 };
ClientToScreen(main_client, &pt);
```

Depending on the target window you may find you can simply post it a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message to simulate the input at the appropriate position:

```
PostMessage(main_client, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(100, 100));
```

Answer (score 2):

`SetCursor()` requires screen coordinates, so you need to calculate where your double-click would be in screen coordinates relative to the window's current screen location.  You can do that by either:

1. using `GetWindowRect()` to retrieve the window's current screen coordinates, then offset that by the intended relative coordinates.
2. use `ClientToScreen()` or `MapWindowPoints()` to convert relative coordinates to screen coordinates.

Once you have the intended screen coordinates, you can pass them to `SetCursor()`.