# Automatically filling a form and running a program

Tags: c++, c, labwindows, cvi

A friend sent me 3 programs, which are written in C or C++. Every program has a form, which is filled and then a button is pressed to perform some calculation. The programs were written in LabWindows/CVI which I've never heard of. He asked me, if it was possible to automatically fill the forms and run the calculation to get the output. I said that one way would be, to modify the program to a console one and run it with parameters (if the number of fields is low).

Does there exist a tool, which could be used to automate the execution of such programs or, if possible, does the LabWindows/CVI have anything which could help me, besides modifying the source?

I thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: I'm sure this question fits the category of: software tools commonly used by programmers (the mentioned tool is commonly used by physicists).

Answer (score 1):

you could use some automated test programs such as http://www.sikuli.org (this is written in java), it is also nice because you can add any java code you want to improve the test and modify it if you really need something extraordinary.

another way would be creating your own "automated test program" using c++ (since you posted this with c++ tag) to create a mouse and keyboard hook that will move the mouse and type characters on your forms.
the following links might help if you want to create your hooks [C++ mouse click on certain spot in window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047478/c-mouse-click-on-certain-spot-in-window), [Global keyboard hook with WH_KEYBOARD_LL and keybd_event (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975916/global-keyboard-hook-with-wh-keyboard-ll-and-keybd-event-windows)